# Can someone help me with getting the class of a div in jquery if statement?

Tags: jquery, css

Ergo: Why wont this work?

I am trying to make an animation function, and it has to change the position of a css div depending on its name.
For example, product 1 doesnt need to change its top position, product 2 does, and product 3 has to even more.

Been struggling with this for hours!

```
if($(this).attr("class") = "product1")
        {
            $(this).cssAnimate({height: '100%',marginBottom:'-350px'}, {duration: 400});
        }
        else if($(this).attr("class") = "product2")
        {
            $(this).cssAnimate({top:'-176px',height: '100%',marginBottom:'-350px'}, {duration: 400});
        }
        else if($(this).attr("class") = "product3")
        {
            $(this).cssAnimate({top:'-352px',height: '100%',marginBottom:'-350px'}, {duration: 400});
        }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }
```

Comment: Where's the HTML? Also, check your operator: `=` is Assignment, `==` `===` for Equality. Also, you might want [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) in case of something like `<a class="product1 link">`

Comment: Please consider changing the value of "top" only, retrieving the class of the attribute only once, etc. It would make the code and intent much easier to think about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider something closer to this:

```js
var topPx;
var productClass = $(this).attr("class");

switch (productClass) {
    case "product1": topPx = "0px";    break;
    case "product2": topPx = "-176px"; break;
    case "product3": topPx = "-353px"; break;
    default: return false;
}

$(this).cssAnimate({
    top:          topPx,
    height:       '100%',
    marginBottom: '-350px'
}, {
    duration: 400
});
```

There are a ton of ways to write this, but I tend to aim towards communication, and eliminating repetitive redundancy. For example, there's no reason to keep getting the `"class"` attribute; presumably it won't change over the lifetime of this code. The parameters to `cssAnimate` are identical except for a single entry, so it makes sense to change only that entry.

I'm not excited about my use of `return` in the switch statement. Options include explicit compares, checking for the presence of `productClass` in array values, etc. It would also be easy to use a map of class to pixel offsets:

```js
var offsets = {
    "product1": "0px",
    "product2": "-176px",
    "product3": "-353px"
};

var productClass = $(this).attr("class");
var offset = offsets[productClass];
if (offset === undefined) {
    return false;
}

$(this).cssAnimate({
    top:          offset,
    height:       '100%',
    marginBottom: '-350px'
}, {
    duration: 400
});
```

You might want to wrap that up in to a method that gets the offset, or possibly returns a map of options that would be merged with the default map.

Comment: Thanks alot, works great!

I actually don't know any jquery and I'm just fumbling through, you have been really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change "=" to "==" for a start.